# How to fix apt with broken ConfigParser import?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pip, apt

Recently, I was having problems with trying to use certbot. Because of this, I was messing around with pip, easy_install, and apt.

Eventually I ended up breaking apt somehow and haven't found the solution to fixing it.

Now if I try to use apt for anything it throws this error:

> Setting up python-pip (8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4) ...
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in 
>       from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
>       File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in 
>       from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
>       ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
>       dpkg: error processing package python-pip (--configure):
>       subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
>       Setting up python-wheel (0.29.0-1) ...
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in 
>       from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
>       File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in 
>       from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
>       ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
>       dpkg: error processing package python-wheel (--configure):
>       subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
>       Errors were encountered while processing:
>       python-pip
>       python-wheel
>       E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

What can I do to resolve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `ConfigParser` is a Python 2 module.  Did you somehow make `/usr/bin/python` point to Python 3?

Comment: @jwodder Good thought, let me look into that

Comment: @jwodder I've confirmed /usr/bin/python points to Python 3 like you thought. Trying to figure out how to change that now

Comment: @CalebB I used this article (https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-change-from-default-to-alternative-python-version-on-debian-linux) to change my system-wide python to 2.7 from 3.5. It worked afterwards. Turns out some part of my apt depends on Python 2 and I set 3 as default some time ago. Cheers!

Comment: For someone run into this problem, this comment might help: `sudo update-alternatives --config python`

Comment: yep that solved the problem regarding the python version

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python 3 you have to install [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) instead of `ConfigParser`.

Comment: is there a way to tell apt/pip to use that instead?

Comment: pip install configparser

Comment: if it shows any error run this code may be it will help `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: can't do sudo apt-get install -f, anything with apt throws the error I'm having problems with